# C++ in-place construction & subsequent destruction: how do I get the right pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, specifications

*Disclaimer: This is a nuanced C++ question relating heavily to a strict reading of the C++ spec.*

In C++, the traditional way to use in-place construction is:

```
void * pStorage = myPooledAllocationFunction ( /*pool number*/1 ) ; // allocate from pool number 1, for example
MyClass * p = new (pStorage) MyClass () ;
```

However it's important to note that `reinterpret_cast<void*> ( p )` does not necessarily equal `pStorage`.

*Side note: I was floored when I just read that placement-new could do so much more as it's really just saying "please call `operator new` with this extra arguments" and the traditional way to use it just happens to have a default implementation in C++.*

I believe the traditional method of deallocating this newly created object is this:

```
p->~MyClass() ;
myPoolDeallocationFunction ( /*pool number*/1 ) ; // deallocate pool 1 in its entirety
```

Which assumes you're in a position to do this. But what if you aren't? What if you need to get that original pointer back from `p`?

Is this valid?

```
p->~MyClass() ;
myPooledDeallocationFunction ( static_cast<void*> ( p ) ) ;
```

The C++ spec *(C++2003: 5.2.9.10)* specifies that it is valid to use `static_cast` to convert from `MyClass*` to `void*` and then back to `MyClass*`.

There's another mention *(C++2003: 3.8.5)* related to this, specifying that you may, after calling the destructor but before deallocating the memory, do a very specific set of things to that pointer. For our purposes, all we care about is that it includes casting it to `void*` (which is valid because the old pointer "points to valid memory").

It doesn't say if that `void*` was the original `void*` used for the in-place construction.

So: **how do I get the original pointer used for in-place construction from the resultant pointer**?

Comment: AFAIK `reinterpret_cast` of pointer can't change its value. Also you need to make absolutely sure that memory returned from  myPooledAllocationFunction is properly aligned.

Comment: @ElohimMeth - that's true, but placement `operator new` can.

Comment: How can `operator new` change the value of address in memory, where it has been told to construct object? That would be black magic. And if that address is not in committed memory at all? It makes no sense. I can imagine such behaviour only if given pointer is improperly aligned, but it should lead to UB.

Comment: @ElohimMeth - I'm not saying it doesn't actually *store* it there, just that the pointer can be different. There's no guarantee AFAIK that the compiler doesn't place an offset between the start-of-the-object and the pointer-you-use-to-reference it, especially in the case of weird inheritance hierarchies. Now, the pointer SHOULD be inside the block you allocated, but even that's not guaranteed.

Comment: I know that if a class has multiple inheritance it can get a different address depending on what base class you cast it to, but I'm not aware of a case where placement new can change the address on its own. If there is such a case I'd love to know about it.

Comment: Even if that's the case, the question still stands because you can destruct the system from any class (assuming the static type and the dynamic type have at least one common base class with a virtual destructor). So if you have a pointer to another static type in the hierarchy with a different address, how do you get the original storage location?

Comment: You can use dynamic_cast<void*> to get the most derived class's address in that case. However, any additional data for the object must go in the object. As far as I know, it's completely illegal for placement new to change the address- the whole point of that feature is to place it at the address you've given it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something guys, as I've never overloaded `operator new`, but I guess we could write an `operator new` that returns a different address from that passed in? I'm referring to the third overload [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/). Is this what the OP was referring to?

Comment: That page explicitly states that the third overload is not replacable.

Comment: The placement "allocation function" is guaranteed to return the original pointer, [new.delete.placement]p2, and may not be replaced (p1). Finding guarantees about the new-expression is a bit harder, but I think [expr.new]p11 guarantees that the address returned from `new` in these cases (where the type is not an array!) must be the same address that the original `void*` refers to. And `reinterpret_cast` is guaranteed to yield the same address, provided everything is suitably aligned, via [expr.reinterpret.cast]p7 and [expr.static.cast]p13.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dynamic_cast<void*>` to retrieve the original pointer from a base class. The resulting pointer will *always* point to the most derived class, a.k.a. the whole object.

As far as I am aware, it is illegal for `pStorage` and `p` to be different addresses.

Comment: I don't think this is true if you use multiple inheritance but don't have a vptr. That is, [expr.dynamic.cast]p6 applies, "Otherwise, `v` shall be a pointer to [...] a polymorphic type.", to p7.

Comment: OTOH, `delete` itself doesn't work w/o a virtual dtor if the static type of the pointed-to object you give it doesn't match its dynamic type. So it has even stricter requirements.

Comment: Firstly, that's terrifying; I did not know that you could do a `dynamic_cast<void*>`, but that does indeed answer one part of the question. However, I cannot find a place in the spec that says that the Dynamic Type's pointer must be identical to the storage pointer.

Comment: The result must point to the object of the most derived type- that is to say, it must be the same as the result of `new (storage) T(...)`. So if we conclude that `new (storage) T();` always returns a strongly-typed `storage`, then we can conclude that `dynamic_cast<void*>(p)` produces `storage`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like this is an academic question that would require a pedagogical answer.

But if you're willing to entertain brute-force-and-ignorance it might serve your purposes to slice your pool blocks out of raw memory on even power-of-two boundaries, resulting in blocks that are guaranteed to be larger than any object to be placemented (and presumably properly aligned).

(Then mask off the appropriate low-order bits of p to get the original new target.)

Answer (score 1):

Most of compilers use a really easy implementation of the placement new, as it's pointed in 11.2.4 in *"The C++ Programming language"*.

For example VS - 2013:

```
 #ifndef __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE
 #define __PLACEMENT_NEW_INLINE
inline void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t, void *_Where) _THROW0()
    {   // construct array with placement at _Where
    return (_Where);
    }
```

But, in the book is not *explicitly* explained if the return of a placement new has to be necessarily the same that the passed pointer.

So, AFAIK, it should work. And the `dynamic_cast<void*>` pointed by @Puppy to retrieve the original pointer looks a great idea.

But, I would like to talk about the explicit destructor calling and, what Stroustrup says about it:

*"Note that explicit calls of destructors should be avoided except in the implementation of resource
management classes."*

I am supposing that, since you have not the original storage pointer in the moment of the destruction it's because it's not performed in a resource management class.

Usually I think that finding those kind of tarpits or questions in C++ programming are related to some design flaws (of course I am not questioning the design of whatever you were doing), but maybe they should be used as signals to think about what exactly we are doing.

In this concrete example, mixing objects allocated with placement new and regular objects without an explicit management class for the ones allocated with placement new, it's not definitely a good idea.

Comment: I agree that mixing them is bad. I'm asking this in case I find another reason to make an allocation pool. Sometimes, it'd be nice to be able to track allocations on an individual basis instead of a per-block basis (the former easily implemented as a linked-list with atomic operations). That's the primary genesis of this question; the other is pure curiosity. Also see my comment on Puppy's answer.